# Light clustered Vert.x

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x

We have many different vertx instances which communicate with each other by clustered EventBus above Hazelcast. It nice works out the box.

But it seems that vertx's implementation is overhead for us. Hazelcast significantly increases a consuming memory of every instance and a start time.
Also we don't use any in-memory storage, we don't use any AsyncMaps and HA features.

Is possible to make inter-vertx communication with minimum impact? Are there any solutions?

**UPD. More details**

I tried vert.x v3.3.3 and v3.4.0, both use hazelcast v3.6.3.
Also I tried newer versions of hazelcast with 3.4 vert.x.

For comparing I run an instance of zookeeper and vert.x based on it.

In total I collected some statistics of initialization phase.
For me, the connecting time to the cluster is more important. Also I noticed that hazelcast loaded a lot of com.hazelcast* classes in the start (about half of all loaded classed in the project)

```
|                              | hazelcast 3.6.3 | hazelcast 3.7.5 | Hazelcast 3.8 | Zookeeper 3.4.8 | No cluster |
|------------------------------|-----------------|-----------------|---------------|-----------------|------------|
| Loaded classes(init phase)   | 2685            | 2703            | 3131          | 257             | 0          |
| Start of the 1st member(sec) | 2.3s±0.2        | 2.4±0.2         | 2.4s±0.2      | 1.0s±0.1        | 0.4        |
| Start of 2d/3d member(sec)   | 4               | 4.5±0.2         | 4.5s±0.2      | 1.0s±0.1        | —          |
```

I used Ubuntu x64 and java8.121

PS: I repeat again I speak about init phase only.

Comment: could you share mode details like versions of the products (vertx and hazelcast), memory footprint recordings (like heap dump). We would love to investigate the root cause. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The discrepancy you notice in your measurements is due to a fundamental difference to the way vertx-hazelcast & vertx-zookeeper cluster managers work:

- When using vertx-zookeeper, your vert.x instance starts an Apache Curator client [1] that connects to an existing Zookeeper cluster: the Zookeeper cluster itself is separately running on other JVM(s).
- When running vert.x with the hazelcast cluster manager, the cluster manager starts a Hazelcast member running embedded within the same JVM: you are not connecting to a separate Hazelcast cluster, you are running a full cluster member in the same JVM as your vert.x instance.

This should at least explain the difference you notice in number of loaded classes. That said, you can start a separate Hazelcast instance and configure the cluster manager to start a lite member [2]. A Hazelcast lite member does not store any data so might be lighter in term of loaded classes and is definitely lighter at runtime as it does not participate in shared data management, it rather acts as a client to clustered datastructures.

In terms of connection time, your results may vary depending on whether you are using multicast, TCP/IP or other cluster discovery method. See more about alternative cluster discovery configuration options in [3].

[1] https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-zookeeper/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/java/index.adoc#how-to-work

[2] http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#enabling-lite-members

[3] http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#discovering-cluster-members

Comment: Could you please let me know the preferred docker image for cluster managers, i am going to use hazelcast/hazelcast:v , and another thing is that do i have to use cluster.xml same in all the the nodes/project and could you please help me with any doc how to change cluster.xml in hazelcast/hazelcast image, help would be appreciated